# How can we recognize the sound of two different sources?

Tags: classical-mechanics, waves, acoustics

Why when 2 or more persons are speaking we can identify the sound source ? How the superposition of the waves make the waves still be heared as they were alone ?

Answer (score 3):

The pattern of subtle echoes that a sound wave produces in your outer ear on its way in to the eardrum is unique for any angle of approach. Your brain deconvolves those signals and can deduce directionality, even if you have only one ear.

Note that this also allows you to tell if a sound is coming from above or below you, even though you do not have an ear in the top of your head or in your nether regions.

Comment: There's an interesting experimental demonstration for this in [Smarter Every Day 173 - Shooting Down a Lost Drone and why Dogs Tilt their Heads](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Oai7HUqncAA)

Answer (score 0):

I think the same way as speech-recognition works. We recall certain 'recorded patterns' that we filter looking if they in some way match (can be found within the) complete waveform.